# Upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 - My User Do not load

Tags: 11.10, login, users

To developers and administration :)

I am developer so my work depends on OS on which I work.

1. As additional software I installed Unity2D desktop from repository and OpenBox.
2. A couple a days ago, when I was working on UNITY_2D, I got the upgrade proposal notification, so I agreed, and the update of my system begun.
3. The update was successful, I turned on my Notebook, then login, but after a couple of minutes borders on my windows disappear. Even if I reload Unity, they continue to disappear each time after a couple of minutes.
4. A couple of days after (I am not sure how many days exactly), I tried  to login to my user - I enter password (password is right) -> Black screen with codes for 2-3 seconds -> And I am again on login screen. I tried all desktops manager and "CTRL   ALT   F1" Terminal: user login is possible only on Terminal sessions, but it do not load Visual desktop.
5. 'Guest' User is working with any desktop, on "root" user I can't login because my password didn't work.

I really like Ubuntu and I understand that developers work a lot of time to bring us a new design and features in 11.10 distro, But after upgrade --- All my system goes to HELL, and my work too.

Comment: 1: was unity-2d installed in your 11.04 or 11.10? I ask because the package is now installed by default in 11.10. 4: what happens if you run Unity from Terminal sessions?

Comment: 1) Unity2D was installed in 11.04 --- 4)From terminal I can enter as My User, but visual desktop (Unity) is Disabled, so I can use only commands as in simple terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  ( It's really working and not a joke )

---

1) Download "Ubuntu 11.10" from official site.

2) Create Live CD or Live USB.

3) Reboot PC -> Start install process -> In the menu chose option UPGRADE UBUNTU TO 11.10.

4) After UPGRADE , all will be working.

---

After upgrade all data will be saved, and all will be working.

There is some problems with sites on XAMP , but easily can be fixed by changing chmod rights to folders.

---

The problem was actually very simple -- in "home" directory was 0 bytes of free space, that's why user do not load.

---

PS: I tried all methods that i found on the internet spend two days for this problem, especially on ubuntu forums - but not one is not working for me, UPGRADE IS THE BEST solution.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather I would check to see if your PATHs have been corrupted somehow. It's possible that GDM or gnome-session are not within the paths of the users for some odd reason. I've noticed that Ubuntu has a strange way of randomly taking PATHs out of most configuration files whenever you change things.

Check what you get on: `echo "$PATH"`

It's one of the gotchas that's plagued me even without an upgrade.

Comment: I enter  command - echo "$PATH". Then I get this - /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new user and seeing how that works?  If that works ok, one option would be to move all the hidden files and folders in your home directory to a backup folder.

Another thing to check with login problems is that your home directory permissions haven't somehow been changed.

Comment: I try next variants: 1) Login as GUEST -> Not enought privileges to create user, SUDO command do not work.  2) CTRL + ALT + F1 -> In terminal I login from my user and try commands "useradd" and "useradd -m -s /bin/bash userName" , after that I get error message - some sord of "Can't lock directory"

Comment: Just as an aside, I believe it's better to use "adduser" than "useradd".  It's a bit higher level and safer.  That won't work as a guest, because the guest won't have root privileges.  Not sure why the second option didn't work though.